# Can't get an IP address

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig, eth0

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04.

I have an onboard network card. The computer usually boots perfectly, but today, I don't have an IP address. The light is on, on the network card as well as the switch. Other computers work in the switch and I tried other ports to no avail.

```
# sudo ifconfig eth0 up
SIOCSIFFFLAGS: Resource temporarily unavailable
# sudo dhclient
... some messages ...
receive_packet failed on eth0: Network is down
```

Driver is `e100`. I tried `modprobe eepro100`, but still same problem.

*Update:* Putting in another network card didn't help! Could it be some sort of IRQ conflict?

Comment: Are the the card's IP settings configured statically or dynamically (e.g. DHCP). If the latter, is the DHCP server up and configured and able to service the request from the client (e.g. spare IP addresses, MAC address table entry correct (if used) &c)?

Comment: `lspci` command should so your card's make and model

Comment: DHCP. And other computers on the network are getting IPs fine. `dhclient` won't even get the packets out since the interface can't come up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to try is to make sure you have link. You can check this using either

```
# ethtool eth0
```

or

```
# mii-tool eth0
```

Look for a line about Link Detected. If it says no, then you have a problem with your network card, network cable or switch.

I wrote a [guide to troubleshooting network problems](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/network-troubleshooting.html) that you might find useful.

Comment: Link Detected : No. :(. Did something die in the motherboard to-do with networking?

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time. Disable the onboard card and plug in another one.

Comment: I'd check the network cable works in another computer and check that the network port works with another cable and computer. This should rule out either of those. As John suggests, try a new network card.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried a different network cable?

Answer (score 1):

Set a static ip adress in /etc/network/interfaces

Something like this, change it to your network config

> ```
> # The primary network interface
> auto eth0
> iface eth0 inet static
>         address 192.168.0.100
>         netmask 255.255.255.0
>         network 192.168.0.0
>         broadcast 192.168.0.255
>         gateway 192.168.0.5
> ```

Then reboot router or other end of your network (computer - router/modem).

Now see what happens. Of still no succes, see if you can set iface eth0 inet DHCP instead of the above...